# Repeat content value of pseudo selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-selectors

On the website of [iA.net](http://ia.net/blog/learning-to-see/) they made section separators with a pseudo element :before to create a nicely dotted line behind the text of the separator. In this case it's the timestamp of the post and the footer "Contact" header.

I'm trying to recreate the effect and the only thing I can come up with that looks similar is this:

HTML:

```
<div class="post-meta post-timestamp">
    <div class="post-date">
        <time datetime="{{date format="YYYY-MM-DD"}}">{{date format='DD. MMMM YYYY'}}</time>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS (SASS):

```
.post-meta {
  padding: 2px 0 10px;
  color: #b3b3b1;
  .post-template & {
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
    margin: 0 0 1.8em;
  }
  .post-date,
  .tag-list {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    margin-top: -0.8em;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .post-date time,
  .tag-list span {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: $body-bg;
    padding: 0 1em;
    i {
      margin-right: 0.24em;
    }
  }
  .home-template & .tag-list span {
    display: inline;
  }
  li {
    display: inline;
  }
}
```

From what I've could find on their website is the following HTML/CSS:

```
<h1 class="section_separator">
    <span>19. March 2013</span>
</h1>
```

CSS:

```
.section_separator {
  font-family: 'iABCRegularSC', Georgia, serif;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 0 1.52381em 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.14286em;
  text-align: center; }
  .section_separator a,
  .section_separator span {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 10px;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #fdfdfd;
    text-decoration: none; }
  .section_separator a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline; }

.section_separator:before,
.section_separator .before {
  font-family: 'iABCRegularSC', Georgia, serif;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -1000px;
  z-index: -1;
  overflow: visible;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  color: #111111;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.14286em;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  content: "ÂµÂµÂµÂµÂµÂµÂµ"; }
```

I've been looking into this one for a while, but can't find out how to recreate it. Although I'm pretty sure they're also using a kind of javascript for this, because when I turn off javascript the separator doesn't render. But I also can't find anything in the javascript that's doing anything with that separator, or maybe I'm just looking in the dead-wrong place.

Does anybody know what they're using here? I'm asking because I just can't figure it out and I'd like to do something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question. I could be wrong, but I am fairly certain that this is what is happening:

The `µ` symbol is being inserted into the page, but they are using a custom font which shows this symbol as a series of dots, about 200px wide. So, it looks like a really massive line of dots when they add a bunch of those symbols in. Then they just slide that line over a bunch, and let `overflow: hidden;` hide the excess dots on each side.

Comment: Indeed a valid idea, but that doesn't explain why it doesn't render when javascript is turned off. The character `µ` still exists in the CSS. And where is the JS that does this then? I can't find it.

Comment: Notice that the font on the text renders differently when javascript is disabled... `fontCss.setAttribute("href", "http://cloudfront.ia.net/wp-content/themes/iA4-0.2/stylesheets/fonts-1-2.css");` The font is loaded using @import within a stylesheet which is loaded with javascript.

Comment: I guess that solves the riddle then. Thanks so much for your help on this. I guess I'll have to come up with something similar, but maybe svg or the likes.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea here to simplify their complexity.

**HTML**

```
<div class="splitter">
   <span>work</span>    
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
  text-align:center;
  margin: 50px;
}

.splitter{
  border-top:1px dotted #ccc;
  margin-top:20px;
  text-align:center;
}

.splitter span{
    position:relative;
    top:-10px;
    background-color:#fff;
    padding:0 20px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
```